# Is there a way to run python code using the output from stdout or a redirection?

Tags: python, cmd, head

Suppose I have a an output from a command like this:

```
C:\> head type_test.py
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello ' + name

print(greeting("John"))
print("foo")
print("bar")

C:\> head type_test.py 6
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello ' + name

print(greeting("John"))
print("foo")
```

And I want to redirect the code to the python interpreter somehow so the output would be:

```
C:\> ???
Hello John
foo
```

I know that I have to redirect the output from the previous command to python, but does python run script when provided directly like this?

Answer (score 3):

Simply do following. It works for me.

```
head -5 type_test.py | python
```

Comment: Nope. It still prints the file rather than executing in python.

Answer (score 0):

use sys.stdin to get piped in stuff.  Suppose I write this program:

file prog.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
x=sys.stdin.read()
print('hello '+x)
```

Then if I do:

```
$>chmod u+x prog.py
```

and then:

```
$>echo john | ./prog.py
```

I get:

```
$>hello john
```

Comment: That's definitely not what I am trying to do.